# javascript multiple file reading by directory

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a site, that read all the text inside a predefined folder. I found a code that is something that i wanted but in this code you have to select the files by file input. i want to make it automatically read all the file's text in the folder and print them.

The code that i found:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Select multiple files to read from your system:</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple />

        <script>
            /**
             *  Simple JavaScript Promise that reads a file as text.
             **/
            function readFileAsText(file){
                return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                    let fr = new FileReader();

                    fr.onload = function(){
                        resolve(fr.result);
                    };

                    fr.onerror = function(){
                        reject(fr);
                    };

                    fr.readAsText(file);
                });
            }

            // Handle multiple fileuploads
            document.getElementById("fileinput").addEventListener("change", function(ev){
                let files = ev.currentTarget.files;
                let readers = [];

                // Abort if there were no files selected
                if(!files.length) return;

                // Store promises in array
                for(let i = 0;i < files.length;i++){
                    readers.push(readFileAsText(files[i]));
                }
                
                // Trigger Promises
                Promise.all(readers).then((values) => {
                    // Values will be an array that contains an item
                    // with the text of every selected file
                    // ["File1 Content", "File2 Content" ... "FileN Content"]
                    console.log(values);
                });
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot directly access the local harddrive from the browser because of security reasons. The only way is via `<input type="file">` or drag&drop from file-explorer to the browser

Answer (score 1):

You could ask for a DirectoryHandle, Save it to IndexedDB and reuse it whenever

```js
const handle = await window.showDirectoryPicker()
```

it's also possible to get a handle from drag and drop

```js
const handle = await dataTransfer.items[0].getAsFileSystemHandle()
```

there is also a sandboxed directory that you can use `navigator.storage.getDirectory()`